# Passing data between two Angular apps

Tags: angularjs, angular, express, session, session-cookies

What I'm currently trying to do is to have an Angular 7 application nested inside an Angular 1.x one. I've created it inside my main AngularJs app, served it using express and opened it via a link in my main application.

Unfortunately, I don't get session data in this nested app, so every call to my API fails, do you know any way I can pass this kind of information between two Angular apps? Is this a viable solution?

Comment: Are you using iframe?

Comment: hi @Piero did you found any solution for above ?